# React hook Redirect on component mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-hooks

I am trying to manage session after successful login while redirecting to some page on form submit.

I would do this usually, in a class component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    if (context.token) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }
}
```

But I want to use React hooks, therefore; the following code is not redirecting anywhere:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
es6
const HomePage = props => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
);

const AboutUsPage = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    redirectTo();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About us</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

function redirectTo() {
  return <Redirect to="/" />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/us">About us</Link>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/us" component={AboutUsPage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-river-6dvyv?fontsize=14

I have read that if the hook `useEffect()` returns a function it will only work when the component unmounts. But it should redirect when the component is being mounted.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `redirect` variable on the state and based on it redirect in render:

```
const AboutUsPage = props => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRedirect(true); // Probably need to set redirect based on some condition
  }, []);

  if (redirect) return redirectTo();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About us</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This works, but why should I use `useEffect()` then if I can make the same logic in `redirectTo()`? I could omit the hook at all and make the function call before returning the JSX.

Comment: That depends, if you just want to do a redirect no matter what then Hook is not needed. But if you have some complex logic connected to component's state that decides whether to redirect or not, you need to use the Hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could have it so that the component selectively renders the page based on whether or not the page is given a token.

```
const AboutUsPage = ({token}) => (
  token ? (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h1>About us</h1>
    </div>
  )
);
```

However, if you would still like to use context when implementing this with React Hooks you can read up on how to use `context` with hooks in this [article](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c). It shows you how you can incorporate `context` into React with only a few lines of code.

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) =>(
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Done with hooks and context, your `AboutUsPage` component would resemble something like this.

```
import { useStateValue } from './state';
const AboutUsPage = () => {
  const [{token}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  return token ? (
    <Redirect to="/" />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h1>About us</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

import {Redirect, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

and inside Switch....

```
<Switch>
      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
</Switch>
```

This solved my issue.