# Route to page inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to produce a minimal example of routing to login if no session is found. Here is my code from `_app.js` inside `pages` folder :

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const router = useRouter()
    useEffect(() => {
        const session = document.cookie.includes("session_active=true")
        if (session) {
            fetch("/api/user")
                .then(u => u.json().then(setUser))
        } else {
            const redirectURI = router.pathname
            const url = {pathname: "/login", query: {"redirect_uri": redirectURI}}
            router.push(url)
        }
    }, [])
    if (!user) return Loading()
    return (<div>User {user.name} {user.surname}</div>)
}
```

My login is inside pages/login.js with this content :

```
const Login = () => (<div>Login page</div>)

export default Login
```

However it's stuck on the loading page even though I don't have the session. Am I misusing the router ?

The URL is changed properly to `/login?redirect_uri=%2Ffoo` but the content is not the one from my `Login`

Below is a stackblitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-supacx-rpl5rm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hook Redirect on component mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515082/react-hook-redirect-on-component-mount)

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to use the router to route to the login page.

Comment: where is `useRouter` defined?

Comment: below `const [user, setUser] = useState(null)`. And it is imported with : `import {useRouter} from "next/router"`

Comment: What is your file structure for the pages folder?

Comment: @AdoRen sure, but the point of the linked answer is to move the redirect out of `useEffect` you could set a new state for `session` and before rendering (like you did for `if (!user)` you could redirect `if (!sessionState)`

Comment: @Nathan in the pages folder I have : `index.js`, `_app.js`, `login.js`

Comment: Seems to be working properly here when recreated? [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-supacx?file=pages/index.js)

Comment: @AdoRen, sorry haven't noticed the next.js tag. In this case you need to move your rerouting logic from `MyApp` to whatever the "main" component in your app is, probably **index.js** in your case. MyApp should just render the `Component` with `pageProps` that are being passed.

Comment: @Nathan if you navigate to `/` it does, but not if you navigate to `/foo` or whatever. Code provided is from _app.js and is supposed to wrap any routes I suppose. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: @tromgy isn't it the purpose of `_app.js` ? I've edited my post with a stackblitz example to add context.

Comment: @AdoRen, the component in **_app.js** is a sort of generic entry point. It shouldn't be "messed with". I've forked your stackblitz to show how it can work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-supacx-otkjse?file=pages/_app.js

Comment: @tromgy thanks; but from your fork, I can freely access to /foo if I type it in the url; which defeat the purpose of a guard if no session is found.

Comment: If you need to protect multiple routes, just wrap them in a "higher order component" that contains all the logic for checking session, redirecting to login, etc. Here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-supacx-dhc7ac?file=components/auth.js) where the route **/foo** is wrapped, while the Home is left as it was, but you can wrap it the same way too.

Comment: Interesting; I was hoping for a default global wrapper instead of a thing to repeat on each and every route I want to protect. But it helps me nonetheless; I like the functional approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem, You are preventing the app to load.

- You are not changing user's state in case there is no `session_active` cookie.
- You are trying to render the only loading component instead of the next App.

```
  if (!user) return Loading()
```

**Solution:**

- Let the app render
- render the loading component inside the return statement of the app component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const session = document.cookie.includes('session_active=true')
    if (session) {
      fetch('/api/user').then((u) => u.json().then(setUser))
    } else {
      setUser(true) // set to true.
      const redirectURI = router.pathname
      const url = { pathname: '/login', query: { redirect_uri: redirectURI } }
      router.push(url)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {!user && <div>loading</div>}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

I am not sure which approach you will use to pass user info to all components. My suggestion would be to create a context for authentication and wrap the app with it. Then handle the user session and redirection in the context.

Comment: Thank you, so the `router.push` method only works if `Component` has previously been loaded. I'll mark as answer :)

Comment: it’s not about component, you are preventing to render the app. And only try to render the loading component. It could only work in other components but not in _app.js file. thank you 